# How to fetch individual pageviews of web pages through google API php client?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-reporting-api

I am new to google APIs and analytics and I have a website linked with Google Analytics and would like to fetch **individual pageviews of each web page**  of the website through google API php client.

I was able to fetch total number of pageviews by the below code, it returns an object with the pageviews figure as a parameter.

`function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
return $analytics->data_ga->get( 'ga:' . $profileId, '30daysAgo', 'today', 'ga:pageviews,ga:sessions');
}`

I went through their documentation but couldn't find a metric value to fetch the needed. Have I missed something somewhere? I am using the bellow package for development,

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question..

Comment: If you want to see the information by the pages why haven't you added the page path dimension?